Circular movement of a mass tied to rod
Consider a mass $m$ tied with an ideal string of length $l$ to a rod and let $\alpha$ be the angle between the rod and the string (there's a gravity force).
If $\omega$ is the (constant) angular velocity of the mass as it moves circularly, I want to understand the maximum value possible for $\alpha$ as a function of $\omega$.
Assume $m \neq 0$, then by the tension force component at the upward direction
we have $\alpha \neq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.
Finally by the condition for the centripetal force, it yields:
$$\alpha = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{g}{l}\frac{1}{\omega^2}\right),$$
where $g$ is the gravity constant.
Now, if $\omega$ is unbounded, it contradicts the assumption $m \neq 0$.
Therefore, it must be that there is a constant $C$ which satisfies
$$\alpha = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{g}{l}\frac{1}{C^2}\right).$$
Does it physically mean, depending on the mass, that once $\alpha$ "exceeds" a certain value, then the mass does not any longer maintain a circular motion and it is not the case that any mass being rotated around the rod can attain $\alpha = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ with circular motion (as I was expecting)?
Is it possible to compute the bound $C$ practically?


To find a maximum angle calculate ${d\alpha}/{d\omega} = 0$ and then solve for $\omega$. A quick check of this with CAS gives that in extremum case $\omega$ is unbounded (infinity) and this makes sense, because perpendicular forces do not interfere. So to say when ball goes higher and higher vertical projection of centrifugal force goes smaller and smaller and so $\pi / 2$ angle can never be reached (only some $\pi / 2 - d\alpha$).

And say we are adding one more ideal string of the same length $l$ tied (symmetrically) from the bottom and observe the mass accelerating. Is the maximum angle same as the angle at which the bottom string is fully taut for the first moment (i.e  when the tension of the bottom string approaches zero)? @AgniusVasiliauskas

I do not understand exact schematics of your next situation,- Can you draw a new picture for that situation ? Maximum angle depends on the real constrains of angular speed,- if you let angular speed to grow in unbounded way,- maximum angle will be same in all situations, independent of ball mass. In addition,- while in rotation,- tension of string can't be zero (or close to it), because it is proportional to the centrifugal force which by definition increases as angular speed increases.

Also note, that under the maximum angle of $\pi/2$ string tension,- like an angular speed,- will also be unbounded since $T=m\omega^2 r$ and $\omega \to \infty$ as $\alpha \to \pi/2$.

What do you mean by "$m \gg 0$"? Any time you write a "much greater than" sign, you have to use it to compare two non-zero numbers of the same dimensions, and you're saying that the ratio of those numbers is much less than 1.  But by this definition, all numbers are many orders of magnitude larger than zero, so this statement is vacuous.

Voting to close as "needs details or clarity".  Happy to vote to re-open once this issue is clarified, though;  it seems like it's central to your argument.

Sorry, what I mean to say is that the mass m is not zero or infinitely small (.i.e negligible) @MichaelSeifert

So why does the assumption that $m \neq 0$ imply that $\omega$ is bounded?  I don't think that's true, and knowing your reasoning will help this question become answerable.

If the tension force is $T$, then $Tcos(\alpha) = mg$ hence I argue that $\alpha$ cannot approach $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Finally if $\omega$ is unbounded then $\alpha$ as a function of $\omega$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $\omega$ is increasing (unboundedly) which contradicts the initial assumption for $m \neq 0$ @MichaelSeifert

All the $m>>0$ stuff is an unnecessary distraction and may be one reason the question has been closed for lack of clarity. I recommend you edit your question and make it more focused.

It seems like you're confusing the limit $\omega \to \infty$ with a physical setup that can be realized.  For any finite value of $\omega$, no matter how large, there is a corresponding value of $\alpha$ that is strictly less than $\pi/2$, (and this value is independent of the mass.  The angle $\alpha$ does approach $\pi/2$ as $\omega \to \infty$ but it never actually attains that value, and so the tension remains well-defined for any value of $\alpha$.  It does get arbitrarily large, but there's no contraction for any finite value of $\omega$.

I agree with @MichaelSeifert that the $m\ne 0$ does not prove anything about the boundedness of $\alpha$ and while I approved your latest edit, I think you should remove the entire argument based on the value of m.

You mean that what I'm missing is that as  $cos(\alpha) $ approaches zero, the tension $T$ approaches infinite s.t $Tcos(\alpha)$ is finite and equals $mg$? @MichaelSeifert

@X4J  If you have a right angled triangle, with one side of length mg, hypotenuse of h and final side b, then as long as mg is non zero the triangle can not become a flat line no matter how large side b is, side h will always be greater than side b and $\alpha$ will never exactly equal $\pi/2$.

@X4J I don't see what the mass has anything to do with the boundedness of $\omega$. You have correctly shown that the angle is independent of the mass. The only exception is if the mass is zero, in which case any angle is possible.

@X4J However, if g was zero (for example the experiment is done in an inertial reference frame, the angle would go to $pi/2$$ ;-)

In this situation, the tension in the string has a force component $f_{\text{up}}$ that balances the weight of the mass and another force component $f_{\text{in}}$ that opposes the centrifugal force. This means the angle is given by $$\alpha = \arcsin{\frac{f_{\text{up}}}{f_{\text{in}}}} = \arcsin{\frac{mg}{m\omega^2 l}}.$$ For $\alpha = \pi/2$ this means that $\left(\dfrac{-mg}{-m\omega^2 l}\right)$ has to be equal to zero.
For that to be possible, and if $m \ne 0$ then either $\omega = \infty$ or $l =\infty$. It is physically impossible for $\alpha$ to be exactly equal to $\pi/2$ because there would be no component of the tension balancing the weight. Since $mg$ is non-zero and remains constant for any $\omega$, the angle $\alpha$ can only asymptotically approach $\pi/2$ and never exactly reach it. The tension in the string has to be unbounded for $\alpha = \pi/2$ and in practice the string will break before the angle gets to $90$ degrees.

Therefore, it must be that there is a constant $C$ which satisfies
$$\alpha = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{g}{l}\frac{1}{C^2}\right).$$

It appears you wish to determine the maximum value $(\omega_{max} = C)$ of the angular velocity that limits the maximum $\alpha$ attainable.
Using Pythagoras, the tension in the string is
$$\begin{equation} T = \sqrt{((mg)^2 + (m \omega L)^2)},\tag{1}\label{eq:1}\end{equation}$$
where $L$ is the stretched length of the string.  The tension must be less than the tensile strength $(S)$ of the string if the string is not to break. Equation \eqref{eq:1} can be solved for $\omega_{\text{max}}$ when $T = S$ to give:
\begin{equation}\omega_{\text{max}} = \frac{\sqrt{S^2-(mg)^2}}{mL}.\tag{2}\end{equation}
Unfortunately, the stretched length of the string $(L)$ is a function of centrifugal force and $\omega$ and so another equation is required.
Using Hooke's law, $(F = k \Delta L)$, the tension $(T = S)$ can also be expressed as:
$$\begin{equation} S = \frac{EA}{l} (L-l),\tag{3}\label{eq:3}\end{equation}$$
where $E$ is the Young's modulus of the string material and $A$ is the cross sectional area of the string.
Since when $T=S$ and $\omega = \omega_{\text{max}}$, we can equate equations \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:3} and solve for $L$, and by substituting the obtained expression for $L$ into equation \eqref{eq:3} we get this fairly complicated equation for $\omega_{\text{max}}$ (The variable for Young's modulus has been changed from $E$ to $Y$ in the Wolfram calculation, because Wolfram Alpha assumes $E$ to be the exponential number).

It's worth noting that in the idealized first-year-physics world of inextensible and infinitely strong strings, $\omega_\text{max} \to \infty$.
